# Pervasive Data Integrator v10 - Transformation statistics (insert/update count)

Tags: pervasive, integrator

I am trying to find a way to return statistics from transformations in Pervasive Data Integrator v10. I see in the link here (http://help.pervasive.com/display/DI1025/Transformation+Object) That WrittenCount is possible to return; however, when I run the process with debug error log I can see that the counts are tracked respectively:

Execution Statistics: [Map]  Total records read: 128 
Execution Statistics: [Map]  Total records written: 128 
Execution Statistics: [Map]  Total records inserted: 128 
Execution Statistics: [Map]  Total records updated: 0

Trying to find a way to reference this data via a macro or some other method to pass back to the db.

Answer (score 0):

`Project("Map").OutputRecordCount`  ==>  return Count of rows output.

Other Objects are `ReturnCode` and `status`; however, `OutputRecordCount` is what you want.